# nagios custom script working locally, returns null in UI

Tags: monitoring, nagios, ruby

I have a custom script that I've defined within my nagios command.cfg and service definitions. When run locally as nagios on the monitoring host, it returns the expected output (a large hash of stats from a redis instance):

```
[nagios@mon1 scripts]$ /etc/nagios/application-nagios/scripts/check_dataquality.rb -w 10 -c 25 -h redis01
Critical: {"DATA.table1":{"ok":135628,"in_progress":2,"failed":0,"warn":0,"started":135630},"DATA.table2.237-2016-04-24":{"ok":26,"in_progress":1,"failed":0,"warn":0,"started":27},"PROCESS.table2":{"ok":6062,"in_progress":118,"failed":0,"warn":0,"started":6180},"PROCESS.table4":{"ok":2868,"in_progress":-10945,"failed":12361,"warn":0,"started":4284},"PROCESS.table5.application/octet-stream":{"ok":6062,"in_progress":118,"failed":0,"warn":0,"started":6180},"PROCESS.table6":{"ok":57,"in_progress":-3782,"failed":0,"warn":13778,"started":10053},"PROCESS.table7":{"ok":1512,"in_progress":0,"failed":2,"warn":0,"started":1514},"PROCESS.table8":{"ok":61,"in_progress":-128,"failed":3,"warn":571,"started":507},"PROCESS.table9":{"ok":82,"in_progress":3,"failed":0,"warn":0,"started":85}}
```

But within my Thruk UI and logs, it returns (null):

[null returned from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrW6.png)

logging shows the same thing:

```
[1461791704] SERVICE ALERT: Blue Team;dataquality-services;WARNING;HARD;5;(null)
```

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the service command output, or some illegal characters here. Any ideas as to why this service command ret

Comment: possibly `SELinux`...

Comment: Did you return an integer error code after the text response? Also try CRITICAL - instead of Critical: . I always use https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nagios-plugins-with-bash-on-ubuntu-12-10 for reference, it works the same in every language.

Comment: Also if it doesn't respond in a second or two it's taking too long.

Comment: Also if it helps you can run check_nrpe with the arguments from your server's commands.cfg manually

Comment: checked the exit status, returns as expected (this was a crit response):

      [nagios@mon1 ~]$ echo $?
       2

The check is only scheduled to run once per hour, but in testing the check takes on average 12 seconds to complete since it's parsing through a lot of data. Is there a default break timer this is hitting, or can I tune this to be more tolerant of a long running check like this one?

Comment: What's the first line of this script? And can you add your service def and command def?

Comment: `define service {
    name                           dataquality-services
    service_description            dataquality-services
    hostgroup_name                 blue-application
    check_command                  dataquality-services!redis01
    use                            generic-check-hourly
} define command {
    command_name        dataquality-services
    command_line        $USER12$/check_dataquality.rb -w 10 -c 25 -h $ARG1$`